# homogeneous vs heterogeneous in documentdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I am using Azure DocumentDB and all my experience in NoSql has been in MongoDb.  I looked at the pricing model and the cost is per collection.  In MongoDb I would have created 3 collections for what I was using:  Users, Firms, and Emails.  I noted that this approach would cost $24 per collection per month.

I was told by the people I work with that I'm doing it wrong.  I should have all three of those things stored in a single collection with a field to describe what the data type is.  That each collection should be related by date or geographic area so one part of the world has a smaller portion to search.
and to:

> "Combine different types of documents into a single collection and add
>   a field across all to separate them in searching like a type field or
>   something"

I would never have dreamed of doing that in Mongo, as it would make indexing, shard keys, and other things hard to get right.

There might not be may fields that overlap between the objects (example: Email and firm objects)

I can do it this way, but I can't seem to find a single example of anyone else doing it that way - which indicates to me that maybe it isn't right.  Now, I don't need an example, but can someone point me to some location that describes which is the 'right' way to do it?  Or, if you do create a single collection for all data - other than Azure's pricing model, what are the advantages / disadvantages in doing that?

Any good articles on DocumentDb schema design?

Comment: There is no "right" or "wrong" way (despite what your coworkers told you). Having said that: People combine content into single collections all the time, including with MongoDB (not sure why you wouldn't dream of that, or why that would make indexing more difficult; indexing is on a per-property basis). With CosmosDB, it does allow you to cost-optimize, and allows you to access heterogeneous data within a single transaction.

Comment: I wouldn't dream of putting inbound emails and users or firms in a single collection.  What would I call the collection?  "melting pot"?  I mean, in what way is the data even related?   The emails do have email addresses and might map to a user, but it doesn't seem like a good technique.  Also, how would you shard that?    And you would have an index on every field in both objects.

Comment: Also, the question has more to do with finding a good source to read about how to design DocumentDB's schema - showing advantages and disadvantages of each, not specifically looking for 'X is the right answer'

Comment: And this is why this question is off-topic. Requires a good discussion around your specific needs, and maybe a rethinking of the concept  of collections. Also: tutorial/reference recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: Think of the logical partition (each will have its own unique partition key) as a table and the collection as the database with multiple tables/partitions in it.

The better you can target your queries at specific partitions, the faster and cheaper they will be (cross partition queries will be a lot slower).

It can be somewhat tough to partition in that in SQL Server, the minimum size you'll get for a database on Azure is 100GB, whereas on Cosmos DB, the maximum size of a logical partition is 10GB currently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. In order to leverage CosmosDb to it's full potential need to think of a Collection is an entire Database system and not as a "table" designed to hold only one type of object.

Sharding in Cosmos is exceedingly simply. You just specify a field that all of your documents will populate and select that as your partition key. If you just select a generic value such as `key` or `partitionKey` you can easily separate the storage of your inbound emails, from users, from anything else by picking appropriate values.

```
class InboundEmail
{
   public string Key {get; set;} = "EmailsPartition";
   // other properties
}

class User
{
   public string Key {get; set;} = "UsersPartition";
   // other properties
}
```

What I'm showing is **still** only an example though. In reality your partition key values should be even more dynamic. It's important to understand that queries against a known partition are extremely quick. As soon as you need to scan across multiple partitions you'll see much slower and more costly results.

So, in an app that ingests a lot of user data. Keeping a single user's activity together in one partition might make sense for that particular entity.

If you want evidence that this is the appropriate way to use CosmosDb, consider the addition of the new Gremlin Graph APIs. Graphs are inherently heterogenous as they contain many different entities and entity types as well as the relationships between them. The query boundary of Cosmos is at the collection level so if you tried putting your entities all in different collections none of the Graph API or queries would work.

**EDIT:**
I noticed in the comments you made this statement `And you would have an index on every field in both objects`. CosmosDb **does** automatically index every field of every document. They use a special proprietary path based indexing mechanism that ensures every path of your JSON tree has indices on it. You have to specifically opt **out** of this auto indexing feature.

Comment: Please be careful when saying something is "exceedingly simple." For shard (partition) keys especially, this is *not* exceedingly simple (nor is it even *simple*), as this can have a major impact on performance.

Comment: I'm not referring to the process by which you select a partition key value. That is admittedly difficult and takes practice and deep understanding of your application's query patterns. I'm talking about how sharding works in CosmosDb. You pick a key. The entire sharding process is then abstracted away from you. As a developer you literally have to do nothing to make this happen as it's entirely PaaS which is **very** different from Mongo.

Comment: @DavidMakogon If you cripple your ability to make efficient queries by picking inappropriate "values" for your partition key, this has nothing to do with the way things are sharded in Cosmos nor does it affect Cosmos ability to continue to efficiently shard.